# How can i catch error in wso2esb, when i send message to web service?

Tags: wso2, try-catch, send, wso2-esb

I have REST service, which return error http 500 (specially). Fault sequence not catch this error. How to catch this error? Thanks!

my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="d"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8080/rest/ris/b"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="MSG" value="==== FAULT CREATED ==="/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your outSequence, when you receive a response from your REST service, you can test HTTP Status code with swith or filter mediator, sample :

```
<filter source="$axis2:HTTP_SC" regex="500">
   <then>
      ...
   </then>
   <else>
      ...
   </else>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a work around, instead of using `<inSequence>` use `<inSequence onError="fault">`
There is a bug that has been logged in jira:

```
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3386
```

Refer the attached `FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT.xml` file in the ticket itself for more clarification

Comment: After discussing with team:

When you haven't define a fault sequence for a proxy, it will not invoke the default fault sequence. This is not a bug but the expected behaviour of ESB product.

Therefore the bug has been converted to an improvement.
So the behaviour after doing the improvement is, if feaultSequence is not specified in the proxy configuration, default fault sequence is treated as the fault sequence of the proxy. Also please note that this is not something specific to FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property itself.